# Running selenium scripts through web

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, webdriver, test-automation-framework

I have developed a web page which takes all inputs for test cases such as: locators, input data, urls to open, etc. I run the page in tomcat server. Whenever I'm executing the test case with that web page, the browser is opening in my local system and goes fine.

I want to share this url so when others use this link to execute the selenium code, the browser should be open in their system.

Is it possible to do this? If so, please let me know.

Comment: Where is the tomcat server? On your local machine?

Comment: Yes right now , it is in my local . Later will move it to production  server

Answer (score 1):

Where ever the selenium library is running is where the browser will run.

If you are planning on putting this on a server, you'll have trouble if there is nobody logged in to the console.

You should look at Selenium Grid which allows the browser to run on a different machine.

There are cloud based services for these clients, for example, Browser Stack https://www.browserstack.com/

Comment: Hello @Bigwave, thanks for your reply. But today I tried to run the test case from my system and my friend system at a time browser was opened for both of them.I am not sure how it is happened

Comment: So, to clarify:
 - Tomcat is still on your machine?
 - Both you and your friend accessed the same URL? 

And when you say "browser was opened for both" do you mean:
a) Two new browser windows opened on your machine? or 
b) A single browser window opened on both your and your friends machine?

Comment: Hello @Bigwave , Yes Tomcat is in my machine. We both accessed the same url (my local server ).For my instance one browser was created in my machine and at the same my friend also found opening browser at the same time in his machine.

Answer (score 0):

Am also looking for a solution can you please help me

0

i Developed a Automation Selenium java program to non IT support guys where they need to simply update the data file with required input data and double click the jar file in order to run the program (this is fine)

But i thought of creating a web page to the end user where he can enter the input details and just click on the run button which automatically triggers the java selenium code.

in place of excel sheet i used MS Access DB and and for web page i developed with JSP file((Net Beans IDE,html &CSS) i successfully developed the front end UI to user where he can update all the required details to run the program.(Basically i developed CRUD operations on the page)

now my problem is i need to read the data from the DB and execute the selenium java program

is there any way to do this?if Yes please suggest me how to proceed further in order to provide user friendly web page to end user to run the automation program

Comment: Please do not post questions as answers. Instead, post a new question. You can find more information about asking questions in the help center (https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help). You should also explain why your question is different from this question.

Comment: Create a weppage where your input data's will be  stored in the database. Now you should create an API to retrieve the datas from the database this should be run in the selenium. Go with nodejs to create easy API's and a quick webpage using ejs template language instead of java